# Memory allocation with broadcasted operation

Tags: julia

I have a loop which goes upto 100000 and each time it finds the index of numbers matching a certain criteria.

x is an array of floats.

```
x = [0.1,0.3,-0.2, 0.4,0.0, 0.9,1.1]
for i = 1:n 
    cr = max(0.0, 0.2*sqrt(i) - 20)
    ftt = findall(x .<= cr)
    #I have other things here but they are not necessary
end
```

How can you avoid memory allocation by using findall in a loop?

Comment: Where does `x` come from?

Comment: Ooops sorry. I should have stated that x is an array of floats NOT "cr is an array of floats" @DNF

Comment: @kkirui you should really have `x` as argument of your function.

Comment: Let's even drop the function. With just the for loop alone, there is a very big allocation in memory which I am asking how to avoid @norok2

Comment: Please make a minimal working example, so we can just copy code and run it. That makes it easier to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that:

```
x .<= cr
```

creates a temporary boolean array the size of `x`.

To avoid that, you could use a comprehension (and `enumerate()` to yield the index along with the value):

```
[i for (i, x_i) in enumerate(x) if x_i <= cr]
```

or a generator (see @BogumiłKamiński comment):

```
(i for (i, x_i) in enumerate(x) if x_i <= cr)
```

depending on what you need to do with it afterwards.

Comment: alternatively you can also consider creating a lazy generator `(i for (i, x_i) in enumerate(x) if x_i <= cr)` as it will allocate even less (which is better depends on what you will want to do later with `fft` object).

Answer (score 5):

Since `findall` returns a variable sized array of indices, the way you've written this inherently involves allocation: that array of indices has to be allocated. If you're going to do something for each index, however, then you could use a loop instead, e.g.:

```
x = [0.1,0.3,-0.2, 0.4,0.0, 0.9,1.1]
for i = 1:n 
    cr = max(0.0, 0.2*sqrt(i) - 20)
    for (index, item) in enumerate(x)
        item <= cr || continue
        # do something with index, item
    end
end
```

This doesn't allocate memory because it operates on each index and item, one at a time instead of returning them all at once.

Comment: Does it mean that broadcasting in Julia brings out memory allocation?

Comment: Yes. It does in languages in like R, and with Numpy too, it's just that those languages don't provide tools that are faster than broadcast. Julia has 1st class broadcasting, but even better methods if you are writing performance critical code.

Comment: @OscarSmith So then which is the 1st class broadcasting that you are talking about? Because in my loop I have some mathematical equations and I am using the @. broadcasting method but seems also to cause the high memory allocation

Comment: broadcasting inherently allocates temporary arrays. That is not Julia specific

Comment: when I mean 1st class, I mean that Julia's broadcasting is as good as any other language's, not that broadcasting is always the best approach in Julia.

Comment: @OscarSmith And this temporary arrays amounts to the higher memory allocation and the end?

Comment: Yes. One thing to note though is that Julia tracks all allocations, not allocations of unique bits of memory, so this code will likely allocate and GC the same bits of memory repeatedly. (ie it won't use up infinite memory, but it will report that it allocates a ton)

Comment: @OscarSmith Would therefore be  a way to avoid the allocation in broadcasting as well as the reported high GC time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197321/discussion-between-kkirui-and-oscar-smith).